# Breaking changes in PromptDialog.Choice?

Tags: c#, botframework

After updating the Microsoft.Bot.Builder NuGet package from 3.5.5 to 3.5.8 the `OnOptionSelected` callback in the snippet below doesn’t get invoked anymore (I get the “Bad selection” response for every click), did something change in `PromptDialog.Choice`?

Thanks

```
    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var options = new List<string> {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"};
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, OnOptionSelected, options, $"How can I help you?", "Bad selection", 5);
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, you are getting the error after clicking on one of the options or are you writing the option value?

Comment: If retries is different than 0, I get the invalid option message, "Bad selection" in the snipped above, I get re-prompted and end up in an endless loop.
If retries is 0, I get "too many attempts" and the OnOptionSelected fires!...

Comment: I got that. But when you click on the option or if you manually write the value?

Comment: Same behavior for typing and clicking. (FYI, I updated my comment above describing what happens when retries are 0).

Comment: I have a sim[;e repro, I can upload it somewhere if you need.

Comment: Are the options pascal case or lower case as in the post code?

Comment: If you want to upload it, that's fine. The answer is still the one I put below. But with lower case options you shouldn't have hit that problem

Comment: Share the link with me please

Comment: You can download the zip from here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aip7VjJav6nz8IgzH5dOB_H4FTxyVg

Comment: I saw your code and yes, it was different from the one posted here. And yes, you are hitting the issue below. As a temporary workaround, make the options lower case: e.g. from "Get Quote" to "get quote"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting a known issue as you can see h[ere](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2685). The change was already merged to master so it will be released anytime soon.

#### Update

A new version containing the fix was just published => https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.5.9

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel, I'll wait for a version higher than 3.5.8 before updating the package.